# Associative array in Swagger (OpenApi 3.0.0)

Tags: swagger, associative-array, openapi

I have an API that always answers with an associative array where there is only one entry with key "data" containing the final result. The result can be an object or array of objects. This is API output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "product1 name",
    "type": "type a",
    "created_at": "2011-09-28T13:20:15+02:00"
  }
}
```

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "product1 name",
      "type": "type a",
      "created_at": "2010-09-28T13:20:15+02:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "name": "product6 name",
      "type": "type f",
      "created_at": "2010-09-28T13:20:28+02:00"
    },
    {
      "id": 17,
      "name": "product17 name",
      "type": "type Q",
      "created_at": "2010-09-28T13:20:42+02:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get swagger to show **data** which is the name of the key, in the docs?

As for now I only get nested array in swagger:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "product1 name",
    "type": "type a",
    "created_at": "2010-09-28T13:20:15+02:00"
  }
]
```

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "product1 name",
      "type": "type_a",
      "created_at": "2010-01-01T18:21:20+02:00"
    }
  ]
]
```

I need the **data** key to be shown in swagger as it comes back from the API. Is it doable? I wasn't able to find any solution to this yet...:/

parts of my yaml file:

```
openapi: "3.0.0"
info:
  version: 1.0.0
paths:
  /products/:
    get:
      summary: List all available products
      operationId: listProducts
      tags:
        - products
      responses:
        200:
          description: Array of products
          content:
            application/json:    
              schema:
                type: array
                items:
                  $ref: "#/components/schemas/Products"
  /products/{product_id}:
    get:
      summary: Get specific product
      operationId: showProductById
      tags:
        - products
      parameters:
        - name: product_id
          in: path
          required: true
          description: The id of the product to retrieve
          schema:
            type: integer
            format: int32
            example: 1
      responses:
        200:
          description: Product object
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: array
                properties:
                  datar: string
                items:
                  $ref: "#/components/schemas/Product"
components:
  schemas:
    Product:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          example: 10
        name:
          type: string
          example: "producta name"
        type:
          type: string
          example: "type a"
        created_at:
          type: string
          format: date
          example: "2010-01-01T18:21:20+02:00"
    Products:
      type: array
      items:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Product"
```

Any help will be much appreciated:)

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

try with a "additionalProperties" in a intermediate layer for a assoc-array, source:  https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/

```
components:
  schemas:
    Product:
      type: object
      properties:
        id:
          type: integer
          format: int32
          example: 10
        name:
          type: string
          example: "producta name"
        type:
          type: string
          example: "type a"
        created_at:
          type: string
          format: date
          example: "2010-01-01T18:21:20+02:00"

    ArrayOfProduct:
      type: object
      additionalProperties:
        $ref: "#/components/schemas/Product"

    Products:
      type: object
      properties:
        data:
          type: object
          $ref: "#/components/schemas/ArrayOfProduct"
```